# SeleniumLibrary Click button/link doesn't work

Tags: robotframework

`Click Link  href=http://www.tays.fi` gives the error message:

> "Link with locator 'href=http://www.tays.fi' not found."

But the item *does* exist on my page:

```
 < a class="ot-landingpage__link" href="http://www.tays.fi" id="yui_patched_v3_11_0_1_1562143051415_173">www.tays.fi< / a >
```

What am I missing here?  Any ideas, please?

Answer (score 1):

The problem with your code is that `href=` is not a valid locator prefix.

[Click link](http://robotframework.org/SeleniumLibrary/SeleniumLibrary.html#Click%20Link) by default will search the id, name, and href of all anchor elements, so you can give the `href` without the prefix:

```
Click link  http://www.tays.fi
```

Comment: wait until page contains  www.tays.fi  <br/>
scroll element into view  www.tays.fi  
Click Link  www.tays.fi   ----> "Element with locator 'www.tays.fi' not found"

Answer (score 0):

Click Link expects a locator, not the href.

In your case

```
Click Link    id=yui_patched_v3_11_0_1_1562143051415_173
```

OR

```
Click Link    class=ot-landingpage__link
```

See documentation

http://robotframework.org/SeleniumLibrary/SeleniumLibrary.html#Click%20Link

Comment: "When using the default locator strategy, links are searched using id, name, href and the link text."

Comment: "Link with locator 'id=yui_patched_v3_11_0_1_1562143051415_173' not found."

Comment: seems that the yui_patched is generated. Try the class one

If class=ot.. does not work, try xpath=a//[@class="ot"]...